# Saving Uploaded File with Unique Name in Folder

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload

I need to save a file(image) to a folder.
If have an image with name "OrignalName", then its saving in their original name in to my specified folder. I'm using

```
string filename = Path.GetFileName(fileupload1.PostedFile.FileName);
GenerateFileName(filename);
fileupload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("Images" + filename));
```

How should i change the filename to a unique such as timestamp (yyyymmddMMss)
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

```
System.IO.FileInfo file = new System.IO.FileInfo(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
    string fname = file.Name.Remove((file.Name.Length - file.Extension.Length));
    fname = fname + System.DateTime.Now.ToString("_ddMMyyhhmmss") + file.Extension;
```

Comment: I like, looked quite confusing to begin with. +1

Comment: this will Append time to your file name if your file name is ABC then you will have ABC_170912040633.jpg 17 is Date 09 month and 12 is year and  min and sec ofDatetime.now

Answer (score 2):

You can concate your file name with current date and time before saving it to database like that:

```
   string strtemp =  filename + System.DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMyyhhmmss");
```

Comment: it wold be much helpful if i use only a time to set a file name!!

Answer (score 2):

You can try with this code

```
var newPath = filename + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyymmddMMss");
fileupload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("Images/" + newPath));
```

Comment: I don't think this will work. you would need to do the date formatting around the `DateTime.Now` portion

Comment: no probs, just to note the Images part that KiranSolkar put in maybe should have a / after it: Server.MapPath("Images/" + newPath)

Answer (score 2):

Easily is save file to location and then rename him

```
string newName = System.DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMyyhhmmss");
Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.RenameFile(file, newName);
```

Comment: This would expect the file to be on the local machine not the server.

Answer (score -2):

Try the following:

```
 int generatedNo = randomNumber.Next(100, int.MaxValue);
 string filePath=Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/finaldesign")+generatedNo+".jpg");
 imageTosave.Save(filePath, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

Comment: Whilst this may answer the question, you should try and explain what the OP was doing wrong and why this solves their problem.